# Verifying a quadrature formula is exact for polynomials of a certain degree

Tags: numerical-methods

Say I have a quadrature used to approximate $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ defined as

$$I(f) = \frac{1}{90} [ 7f(0) + 32f(1/4) + 12f(1/2) + 32f(3/4) + 7f(1) ]$$

How would I verify that this formula is exact for polynomials of degree $\leq 4$?

Answer (score 0):

Any polynomial of degree$\le4$ can be determined with the help of its values at $5$ distinct points. Let $x_i={i\over4}(0\le i\le 4)$. If $f$ is a polynomial of degree$\le4$, using Lagrange interpolation we have
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^4\left(\prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^4{x-x_j\over x_i-x_j}\right)f(x_i)\\
\implies\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\sum_{i=0}^4\left(\int_0^1\prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^4{x-x_j\over x_i-x_j}dx\right)f(x_i)
$$ 
The constant in front of $f(1)=f(x_4)$ in the above expression is 
$$
{32\over3}\int_0^1x\left(x-{1\over4}\right)\left(x-{1\over2}\right)\left(x-{3\over4}\right)dx={32\over3}\int_0^1\left(x^4-{3\over2}x^3+{11\over16}x^2-{3\over32}x\right)dx\\
={32\over3}\left({1\over5}-{3\over8}+{11\over48}-{3\over64}\right)={7\over90}
$$
The other constants can be obtained through similar calculations.